# Selenium couldn't point the control having special symbol like # , @, $

Tags: selenium, web, driver, selenium-webdriver, xpath

I want to click on radio option button whoose Xpath and Id information are following:-

```
<input id="ContentView_PageLayout_FlightFinderTab_HomepageTabs_FlightsTab_pnlTripType_TripType#0" 
type="radio" onclick="showHideReturningDate('return');" checked="checked" value="Return" 
name="ContentView$PageLayout$FlightFinderTab$HomepageTabs$FlightsTab$pnlTripType$TripType">
```

Xpath:

```
//*[@id="ContentView_PageLayout_FlightFinderTab_HomepageTabs_FlightsTab_pnlTripType_TripType#0"]

<input id="ContentView_PageLayout_FlightFinderTab_HomepageTabs_FlightsTab_pnlTripType_TripType#1" 
type="radio" onclick="showHideReturningDate('oneway');" 
value="One Way" name="ContentView$PageLayout$FlightFinderTab$HomepageTabs$FlightsTab$pnlTripType$TripType">
```

Xpath:

```
//*[@id="ContentView_PageLayout_FlightFinderTab_HomepageTabs_FlightsTab_pnlTripType_TripType#1"]
```

I tried these method to get the ID:

1:

```
return By.XPath("(//input[@id="++'ContentView_PageLayout_FlightFinderTab_HomepageTabs_FlightsTab_pnlTripType_TripType#1']");
```

2:

```
return By.Id("ContentView_PageLayout_FlightFinderTab_HomepageTabs_FlightsTab_pnlTripType_TripType#1");
```

3:

```
return By.XPath("//*[@id=" + '"' + "ContentView_PageLayout_FlightFinderTab_HomepageTabs_FlightsTab_pnlTripType_TripType#1" + '"' + "]");
```

Answer (score 0):

driver.findElementById("ContentView_PageLayout_FlightFinderTab_HomepageTabs_FlightsTab_pnlTripType_TripType#1").getAttribute("name") this does work for me... returns the correct value.  Tried on Firefox with 2.25

Answer (score 0):

Why don´t you use the PageFactory.initElements(...) method with the @FindBy annotation?

Create a field with the @FindBy annotation in your class like:

```
@FindBy(xpath = "//input[@id='IdValue']")
WebElement radioOption;
```

After, call the PageFactory.initElements(driver,this) before your method call.

This will create a dynaproxy to the field and you can access the radio option in your code in a cleaner way.